# About Javascript scope chain

Tags: javascript, function, chain

what's the difference between them ? 
 ①function's scope-->②[[scope]]---->③scope

```
var scope = 'window';
var someFunction = function(){
    something go here....
}
```

someFunction's scope
someFunction[[scope]]
window scope 
is that right?

Comment: Please make your question clearer. I have no idea what you are asking. Variables in Javascript are either local to a function, or global: there are no other possibilities.

Comment: In your example, there are only two "scopes" which are called lexical environments now: (1) The function's scope, (2) the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to understand the scope chain, you should read Richard Cornford's article on [JavaScript Closures](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/), particularly the part on [Identifier Resolution, Execution Contexts and scope chains](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/#clIRExSc).

Briefly, the scope chain travels from variable/activation object to variable/activation object, stopping with the global object (since the global object is effectively the activation/variable object for the global execution context).

So in the case of:

```
var fred;

function foo() {
    alert(fred);
}
```

The identifier *fred* is made a property of the global variable/activation object (which in the case of global code is the global objet itself). When *foo()* is called, a new variable/activation object is created with a scope chain that includes the global object. The identifier *fred* is first resolved on the internal variable object, and since it won't be found there, the next object on the chain (the global object) is searched.

Similarly for:

```
function foo() {
    function bar() {
        alert(fred);
    }
    bar();
}
```

So when *foo()* is called, it then calls *bar()*, and now *fred* is resolved against firstly bar's variable object, then foo's, then the global object.

Once you understand *execution context*, you will also realise why calling the value of *this* "context" is misleading.

Comment: Variable/Activation objects are called *environment records* since ES5... and the `[[Scope]]` of a function stores its *lexical environment* (which is the owner or the *environment record*).

Comment: Thanks, must get deeper into ES5, I've been a bit lazy and sort of ignoring it for now. But I guess the time has coming to get stuck in.